# Cannot connect to my server on AWS EC2(Windows)

Tags: amazon-ec2

I made simple server and It's running as

```
./myserver.exe IP=0.0.0.0 PORT=4600
```

Of course 4600 inbound for public IP is already opened but I can't connect from outside.

I can connect to 3389 for RDP connection but cannot to 4600.
Did I miss something? Should I do something more?
any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Did you open port 4600 both in AWS security group and in windows built-in firewall?

Comment: It's built-in-firewall conf.! thnks!

Answer (score 0):

Windows Firewall wasn't opened.